# NAs introduced by coercion when using rsf (resource selection function) in R

Tags: r, selection, nas

What in the world am I doing wrong? Do I need to worry about these NAs?

I'm using the rsf function in the ResourceSelection package of R. Below is my code with output and the warning message.

>

```
 ## Read CVS Files
> brood <- read.csv("GrouseBroodData2014.csv")
> randoms <- read.csv("Randoms.csv")
> all <- read.csv("2014Broods_AllData.csv")
> 
> #brood
> #randoms
> 
> #summary(brood)
> #summary(randoms)
> 
> #kdepairs (brood)
> #kdepairs (randoms)
> 
> 
> rsf(Pres~VOR+LD+MXHT+X.grass+X.forbs+X.sedges+X.rush+BG+Litter, all, m="Group" , B=100, model = TRUE)
  |++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++| 100%

Call:
rsf(formula = Pres ~ VOR + LD + MXHT + X.grass + X.forbs + X.sedges + X.rush + BG + Litter, data = all, m = "Group", 
    B = 100, model = TRUE)

Resource Selection Function (Exponential RSF) model
Matched Used-Available design
Maximum Likelihood estimates

Coefficients (log link):
     VOR        LD      MXHT   X.grass   X.forbs  X.sedges    X.rush        BG    Litter  
 -0.1945   -1.3590    0.1585   -0.3078   -0.3009   -0.2647    1.0375   -0.3502   -0.3487  

Warning message:
In rsf.fit(X = X, Y = Y, m = m, link = "log", B = B, inits = inits,  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

Comment: we really need a reproducible example.  Are you by any chance including resource categories that sum up to 1?

Comment: Here is a link to the dataset:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/54h3bsc3goo0usk/GrouseBroodData2014.csv?dl=0

Nothing should some to 1 though a few of the variables should sum to 100 (or close to it).

Comment: The point is that if the predictor variables are collinear (as they will be if some of them represent a composition of habitat proportions), then any underlying linear modeling framework will give you NAs.  This must be discussed somewhere, but I don't have an immediately handy link.